i get the message permission denied when ever the code is supposed to remove a file
just to give some context this part of the code is supposed to be deducting gold from the player and to do that i am deleting the old file which contained the username password gold balance and gem balance and i am moving the rest of the info to a new temp file but after changing the gold balance
this is the relevant part of the code
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>  // For opening files
#include <cstdlib> //for random function
#include <ctime> //for time function
#include <sstream>
#include <sys/stat.h>
using namespace std;
int const MAX = 100;
int const MAX_LINE_LENGTH = 300;
void removeInputFile() {
    if (remove("logins.txt") == 0)
        cout << "logins.txt removed successfully." << endl;
    else
        cerr << "Error removing logins.txt" << endl;
}

void renameOutputFile() {
    if (rename("logins_temp.txt", "logins.txt") == 0)
        cout << "logins_temp.txt renamed to logins.txt successfully." << endl;
    else
        cerr << "Error renaming logins_temp.txt to logins.txt" << endl;
}
int chest1(const char* username, int max){

    
    string line, str_username, str_password;
    int gold_balance, gem_balance;

    // Open the input file
    ifstream inputFile("logins.txt");
    if (!inputFile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error opening input file\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // Open the output file
    ofstream outputFile("logins_temp.txt");
    if (!outputFile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error opening output file\n";
        inputFile.close();
        return 1;
    }
int updated_gold_balance = 0;
 while (getline(inputFile, line)) {
        istringstream iss(line);
        if (iss >> str_username >> str_password >> gold_balance >> gem_balance) {
            if (str_username == username) {
                 gold_balance -= 10;
                 updated_gold_balance=gold_balance;
                cout << "\nYour GOLD NOW is: " <<updated_gold_balance << "\n";
            }
            outputFile << str_username << " " << str_password << " " << gold_balance << " " << gem_balance << "\n";
        } else {
            outputFile << line << "\n"; // Output the line as is if it doesn't match the format
        }
    }

    inputFile.close();
    outputFile.close();
     
// Attempt to delete the original file
    if (remove("logins.txt") == 0) {
        std::cout << "Original file deleted successfully.\n";
    } else {
        // Print error message and error number
        std::perror("Error deleting original file");
        std::cerr << "Error number: " << errno << std::endl;

        // Change the file permissions to allow deletion
        chmod("logins.txt", S_IWRITE);

        // Try deleting the file again
        if (remove("logins.txt") == 0) {
            std::cout << "Original file deleted successfully.\n";
        } else {
            std::perror("Error deleting original file after changing permissions");
            std::cerr << "Error number: " << errno << std::endl;
        }
    }

    // Rename the temporary file to the original filename
    if (rename("logins_temp.txt", "logins.txt") != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error renaming file\n";
        return 1;
    }

 ofstream inventoryFile("inventory.txt", ios::app); // Open the file in append mode
    if (inventoryFile.is_open()) {
        // Write the outcome to the file
        inventoryFile << "Outcome of chest opening for user " << username << ": ";
        // Write the outcome here
        inventoryFile << "Gold balance after deduction: " << updated_gold_balance << endl;
        inventoryFile.close();
        cout << "Outcome of chest opening written to inventory.txt.\n";
    } else {
        cerr << "Error opening inventory file for writing.\n";
    }


    // Generate a random number between 0 and 9999 (for 0.1% granularity)
    int random_number = (rand() % 10000) + 1;

    // Check the range of the random number to determine the outcome
    if (random_number <= 6000) {
          //Outcome: A (60%% probability)
        return gold();

    } else if (random_number <= 8000 && random_number > 6000) {
            return common();

        
         //Outcome: B (20%% probability)
    } else if (random_number <= 9110 && random_number > 8000) {
         //Outcome: C (11%% probability)
                 return rare();

    } else if (random_number <= 9710 && random_number > 9110) {
        //Outcome: D (6%% probability)
        return gem();
         
    } else if (random_number <= 9910 && random_number >9710) {
        //Outcome: E (2%% probability)

       
                 return epic();


    } else if (random_number <= 9950 && random_number > 9910) {
        //Outcome: F (0.5%% probability)
        return weapon();

    } else if (random_number <= 9990 && random_number > 9950) {
        //Outcome: G (0.4%% probability)

        
        return legendary();

    } else {
        //Outcome: H (0.1%% probability)
        return ship();
    }
   
    return 1;

}
bool checkCredentials(const string& username, const string& password, int* gold_balance, int* gem_balance) {
    ifstream file("logins.txt");
    string stored_username, stored_password;
    int stored_gold, stored_gems;
    while (file >> stored_username >> stored_password >> stored_gold >> stored_gems) {
        if (username == stored_username && password == stored_password) {
            *gold_balance = stored_gold; // Assign the value to the pointer
            *gem_balance = stored_gems;  // Assign the value to the pointer
            file.close();
            return true;
        }
    }
    file.close();
    return false;
}
int play( const char* username ,int max ,int gold_balance ,int gem_balance) {
    srand(time(NULL));

do {

        int pick;

        cout << "\n[1] BASIC chest 10 GOLD\n"; //chest 1
        cout << "\n[2] RARE chest 50 GOLD\n"; //chest 2
        cout << "\n[3] EPIC chest 100 GOLD\n"; //chest 3
        cout << "\n[4] MEGA chest 450 GOLD\n"; //chest 4
        cout << "\n[5] LEGENDARY chest 1000 GOLD\n"; //chest 5
        cout << "\n[6] EXIT THE GAME\n"; //EXIT
        cout << ">>"; //chest 5
        cin >> pick;

        switch (pick) {
            case 1:
                if (gold_balance<10){
                    cout<<endl<<"You dony have enough gold"<<endl;
                }
                else{
                chest1(username, MAX);
                break;
                }
            case 2:
            
             if (gold_balance<50){
                    cout<<endl<<"You dony have enough gold"<<endl;
                }
                else{

                chest2(username, MAX);
                break;
                }
            case 3:

             if (gold_balance<100){
                    cout<<endl<<"You dony have enough gold"<<endl;
                }
                else{

               chest3(username, MAX);
                break;
                }
            case 4:

             if (gold_balance<450){
                    cout<<endl<<"You dony have enough gold"<<endl;
                }
                else{


               chest4(username, MAX);
                break;
                }
            case 5:

             if (gold_balance<1000){
                    cout<<endl<<"You dony have enough gold"<<endl;
                }
                else{


               chest5(username, MAX);
                break;
                }
            case 6:
                cout << "EXITING....";
                
                return 0;

            default:
                cout << "Invalid choice! Please try again.\n";
                break;
        }
    } while (true);

    
    return 1;
}

int login(){

            int gold_balance = 0;
            int gem_balance = 0;
            string stored_username, stored_password;

            ifstream file("logins.txt");
            if (!file.is_open()) {
            cout << "Error opening file!\n";
            
            return 0;
             }

            char line[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
            // Read a line from the file
            if (!file.getline(line, sizeof(line))) {
            cout << "Error reading file!\n";
             file.close();
             
             return 0;
            }
    
            cout << "Enter your Username: ";
            string username;
            cin >> username;

            cout << "Enter your Password: ";
            string password;
            cin >> password;

           if (checkCredentials(username, password, &gold_balance, &gem_balance)) {
        cout << "Log in successful" << endl;
        cout << "You have " << gold_balance << " gold" << endl;
        cout << "You have " << gem_balance << " gems" << endl;
               
              int choice2;
              
              cout<<endl<<"[1]PLAY"<<endl;
              cout<<"[2]FIGHT"<<endl;
              cout<<"[3]COLLECTION"<<endl;
              cout<<"[4]INVENTORY"<<endl;
              cout<<"[5]STORE"<<endl;
              cout<<"[6]SETTINGS"<<endl;
              cout<<"[7]EXIT"<<endl;
              cout<<">>";
              cin >> choice2;

            switch(choice2){
                
                case 1:
               play(username.c_str() ,MAX ,gold_balance ,gem_balance);
                
                
                break;
                case 2:
                fight();
                 break;
                case 3:
                collection();
                 break;
                case 4:
                inventory();
                 break;
                case 5:
                store();
                 break;
                case 6:
                setting();
                //GAME DISCRIPTION (CARD DROP RATE , EXPLAINATION , )
                
                //CHANGE PASSWORD
                
                 break;
                case 7:
                cout<<endl<<"EXITING...."<<endl;
                return 0;
                break;
            }


                
               file.close(); 
             }else {
                cout << "Invalid Username or password" << endl;
            }
             return 0;
           

}

int signup(){
    int gold_balance = 500;
    int gem_balance = 0;
             cout << "Enter your new Username: ";
            string new_username;
            cin >> new_username;

            ifstream file("logins.txt");
            string stored_username, stored_password;
            bool usernameExists = false;
            while (file >> stored_username >> stored_password) {
                if (new_username == stored_username) {
                    usernameExists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            file.close(); // Close the file before returning`your text`

            if (usernameExists) {
                cout << "username is already taken" << endl;
            } else {
                cout << "Enter your new Password: ";
                string new_password;
                cin >> new_password;

                // Open a file in append mode to store the new email and password
                ofstream outFile("logins.txt", ios::app);
                if (outFile.is_open()) {
                    outFile << new_username << " " << new_password <<" "<<gold_balance<<" "<<gem_balance<< endl;
                    outFile.close();
                    cout << "Your account was made successfully" << endl;
                } else {
                    cout << "Unable to open file" << endl;
                }
            }
            return 1;

}


i tried everything i saw on the web about the (permission denied )message but none worked i thought the problem is from vs code it doesnt have authority but after i gave it alot of authority it still shows the same message.
(Your GOLD NOW is: 99990
Error deleting original file: Permission denied
Error number: 13
Error deleting original file after changing permissions: Permission denied
Error number: 13
Error renaming file)
this is the message i get in the terminal when i run the code and do the open chest command.
i am expecting it to deduct gold and put the new info into a new file called logins_temp.txt and after that rename that file to logins.txt as normal

Please try to create a [mre] to show us, with emphasis on the minimal part. The code you currently show is just too complex to follow and understand what's happening. It's also way to much that is just not relevant to the problem you're having.

I also recommend you take some time to think about the program and the code and what it does. You have just a couple of very long and complex functions. Try to keep functions and classes as simple as possible, preferably doing just one small and simple thing. Yes, you need to create more functions, but it will make the program better, easier to debug, easier to test, and much easier to maintain.

Maybe you don't have permission to do what you want. Maybe the file is still open. Maybe your antivirus is the problem.

Does the file have permission to be deleted?

What do you mean by does the file have permission where does it get permission from
